Is it possible to disable a Prometheus Alert without removing it?
I would like to know how to disable a Prometheus Alert without deleting it please.
I thought about adding "AND false" at the end of the alert query, but I'm not sure if this approach will work for all cases in the future, and honestly I'm not sure how PromQL handles the booleans values.
Example: sum(http_requests_total) > 0 AND false
Thanks!

If you'll edit query anyway - just put _ # before it.
_ is a valid query, that should never return result (and thus never trigger alert) and # will comment-out rest of the query.

AND false (or equivalent and _) might not work for some queries. For example, if query contains top lever or

You can silence an alert through the AlertManager web UI or in Grafana.

Better Alternatives to Disable a Prometheus Alert

Use for with a Long Duration

If you don't want the alert to be deleted, you can set the for field in the alert definition in your config file , check in the configuration the rules then set the for 9999h per example and expr: sum(http_requests_total) > 0
